# Sorry something went wrong editing form web part

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, web-part, edit-form

Whenever I try to edit the form web parts I get an error saying sorry something went wrong.  I get the same error on any list for any part.

I'm certain it's something simple I'm missing, but my googling skills have failed.

I am able to use the customize in InfoPath or pull them up in sharepoint designer.  I'd wanted to use the web designer as it seemed to be the easiest for a newbie.

Your help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You have tagged this question with "2013" and "sharepoint-online". Is it SharePoint 2013 on premise or is it SharePoint Online (which is more likely SharePoint 2016+)?

Comment: This is sharepoint 2016+ I use sharepoint designer 2013 a good bit which is why I tagged that

Answer (score 1):

Switching to SharePoint classic alleviated the issue.

Thanks guys,